# node.js streaming/real-time api implementation

Tags: node.js, api, streaming, real-time

Does anyone have any links to resources or suggestions for building a streaming or realtime api like twitter firehose, facebook updates realtime api, instagram real-time api, etc in Node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I helped develop the DataSift streaming API and I've been working on a node module for easily creating HTTP or WebSocket firehose streaming API's out of any data source you like. https://github.com/ollieparsley/node-firehose hope you find it useful.

Comment: thanks for the info, i appreciate the reference and your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad.

Maybe you are looking for http://socket.io/ ?

When it comes to Web APIs, a good understanding of [REST](http://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-introduction) is helpful before going anywhere complex.

Comment: your answer is even more broad, those apis are very specific and I am looking for technical documentation or reference code of their architecture.